# Split a String Based on Strings in an Array

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, list, split

Given a String...

```
M0 Apple Sauce M1 Peanut Butter M2 Porcupine M3 Quesadilla M4 Margarita
```

How could I split that String into..

```
M0 Apple Sauce
M1 Peanut Butter
M2 Porcupine
M3 Quesadilla
M4 Margarita
```

Is there a way to put `M0, M1,..., M4` in an array, and then use that array to split the string?

Comment: Better, use a regex  - `Regex.Split(s, "(?!^)(?=\bM\d+\b)")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was just reading about that, could you give an example using my above example?

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? (e.g., DataTable with 2 columns, 1 column, or an array of strings?)

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f!%5e%29%28%3f%3d%5cbM%5cd%2b%5cb%29&i=M0+Apple+Sauce+M1+Peanut+Butter+M2+Porcupine+M3+Quesadilla+M4+Margarita), *Split List*.

Comment: Just tested Wiktor's regex string and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @Sturgus I'm looking for either a list or array of strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full credit to [Wiktor Stribizew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353040/split-a-string-based-on-strings-in-an-array#comment73769310_43353040):

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim stString As String = "M0 Apple Sauce M1 Peanut Butter M2 Porcupine M3 Quesadilla M4 Margarita"
        Dim arrString() As String
        arrString = Regex.Split(stString, "(?!^)(?=\bM\d+\b)")
        For Each st As String In arrString
            MessageBox.Show(st)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Regex explanation:

The fact that the regex string is being used in a split method means that your regex pattern's goal is to find positions in the string upon which to split.
The first segment of the regex string `!?^` simply asserts that there is to be no 'match' at position 0.  We do have a match at position 0, but we don't want a 0-length string in the output, so we use this stipulation.  I'll breakdown the second subexpression `?=\bM\d+\b`:

- `?=` is used to say "we're looking ahead of the cursor for matches of the following pattern" - without consuming the text
- `\b` adds that the match must occur where an alphanumeric character is beside a non-alphanumeric character (in this case, always a space and an `M`); this is any 'word boundary'
- `M` is indeed the literal character match of `M`
- `\d` matches any decimal digit
- `+` means that there may be any number of decimal digits in a row at this point (one or more decimal digits)
- The last `\b` details that the digit(s) end with another word boundary

Comment: Awesome, I'm confused as to why `"(?!^)(?=\bM\d+\b)"` does the job?

Comment: @Bob, Yeah, you'd have to brush up on [regular expressions syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to fully understand it.

Comment: But simply put... that expression looks for the letter `M` plus an integer? The code i'm going to be using this in will have `M`'s all the way up to `M60`. Will it work for that?

Comment: @Bob Looks like it will.  Can you not give it a test?  It works fine for M60 in a quick test on my end.

Comment: You may keep it, just explain what the pattern means. Without explanation, a great number of regex-related answers are not helpful.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I took a stab at it.  Please let me know if I got anything wrong.

Comment: Yeah, almost. `(?=...)` is  a positive lookahead that only checks for the pattern match, but does not consume text. `\b` matches a word boundary (not just alphanumeric/non-alpha transitions). `+` match 1 or more instances, not any.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to split parts with regular expression.

```
    Dim stringToSplit As String = "M0 Apple Sauce M1 Peanut Butter M2 Porcupine M3 Quesadilla M4 Margarita"
    Dim stringParts = Regex.Split(stringToSplit, "(?!^)(?=\bM\d+\b)")
    For i = 0 To stringParts.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(stringParts(i))
    Next
```

This code will produce following output:

M0 Apple Sauce

M1 Peanut Butter

M2 Porcupine

M3 Quesadilla

M4 Margarita

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a great answer for this kind of wonky stuff.  But there are other ways if you don't like Regex.  The Step keyword can do this.

```
Dim sText As String = "M0 Apple Sauce M1 Peanut Butter M2 Porcupine M3 Quesadilla M4 Margarita"
    Dim split() As String = sText.Trim.Split(" ")
    Dim sResult As String = String.Empty
    For i = 0 To UBound(split) Step 2
        sResult &= split(i) & " " & split(i + 1) & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox(sResult)
```

Just remember to ensure the data is always in pairs, and each element is separated by a space.

Good luck!